# Problems with ScriptDB Type Equivalences

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted to ask if anyone had problems with ScriptDB Type Equivalences last week. On 10 July when I was performing queries about numeric values, only the query with the numeric value was returning the proper results. In documentation it is said that:

> What that means is if you have a an object with a numeric value, you
>   can query upon the string version of same. For example, if you store
>   the object {a: 23}, you can query on {a: "23"} and ScriptDb will find
>   the previous object.

But the latter version of the query with the string parameter was returning nothing. 
Now it seems to be OK, both versions work as expected.

Has anyone noticed the same problem recently?

Answer (score 1):

There was a logged issue related to indexing and resolving of searching by integer values on the day you note.

There is a resolution proposed in the issue tracker.

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2999

> Thanks for your patience; we believe the underlying issue is now resolved. However, we have not retroactively fixed any data you may have saved or resaved over the last two days. Any data you saved during that period is stored safely, but queries to those objects will still fail if the data type does not match exactly. For example, the property {id: 4074} will match {id: 4074} (number), but not {id: '4074'} (string) or {id: true} (Boolean test).
>
> If you need to query data from the last two days without the data type matching exactly, you will need to resave the records by retrieve them from ScriptDb and rewriting them in place, using something like the sample function below:

```
function resaveRecords() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var records = db.query({}); // get all records
  while (records.hasNext()) { // loop through records
    var item = records.next();
    db.save(item);            // resave with the same ScriptDb ID
  }
}
```